# Would SQLite for Python be helpful for a file this size?

Tags: python, sqlite, bigdata

I have a file of around 60 million lines. I am trying to constantly query the file to find information for a list of names. Each line in the file contains a name followed by relevant information. I tried to build a dictionary but the file was too big.

Many suggesting SQLite for Python. Would that be helpful for a file this size?

Comment: use `numpy` to get information from file .

Comment: numpy can store that much information?

Comment: How big is a line? The amount of memory required is a function of line length and record count.

Comment: No. information will be stored in file . but to get information quickly , u can use numpy.

Comment: the line consists of a name and three integer parameters

Comment: can you explain what numpy function I should use?

Comment: memcache or a actual database engine would be preferred, but sqlite will do the job al tho a bit slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Linux Power tools.
Awk can do your work very easily.

Suppose your file looks like this

```
name1 a b c

name2 e d r t

name3 x y
```

and you want to find info of name2. then using this command you can find

```
awk -F" " -v name=name2 '{if(name==$1){$1=""; print $0}}' filename
```

it will output only info of name2 like this

```
e d r t
```

you can pass multiple name and manage your logic

Comment: you can write your script in a file and invoke that file using -f option.
awk -f script_filename input_filename